# Pandas get_loc with datetimeindex failing

Tags: python, pandas, datetimeindex

I have a time-indexed dataframe, and I want to find what row number matches the closest time to a given time.

For example,:

```
import pandas as pd

findtime = pd.Timestamp('2019-12-12 10:19:25', tz='US/Eastern')
start = pd.Timestamp('2019-12-12 0:0:0', tz='US/Eastern')
end = pd.Timestamp('2019-12-13 0:0:0', tz='US/Eastern')
testindex = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='5s')
testindex.get_loc(findtime, method='nearest')
```

However, this throws an error:

```
UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'subtract' cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('O')
```

If it matters, this is Pandas 1.0.1, on python 3.8.1 64-bit on Windows 10 1909.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is "findtime", how is it defined?

Comment: Fixed my original post, thanks. findtime = pd.Timestamp('2019-12-12 10:19:25', tz='US/Eastern')

Comment: When `findtime` is defined like this, it works for me, I get 7433 as the result. I'm guessing `findtime` is created differently, wherever you get it from in your actual code.

Comment: @cs95 solved. The problem is in pandas 1.0.1, it works in 0.25.3.